# is there any bug about selectionKey.attachment() in java nio?

Tags: java, kotlin, nio

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val selector = Selector.open()
    val sc = SocketChannel.open()
    sc.configureBlocking(false)
    sc.connect(InetSocketAddress(1234))
    val key = sc.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT)
    println("key=$key")
    key.attach(ClientAttachment())

    writeThread(sc)

    while (selector.isOpen) {
        if (selector.select() == 0) continue

        val keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator()
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            val key = keys.next()
            println("key=$key")
            println("ac=${key.attachment()}")
            keys.remove()
            if (key.isConnectable) {
                val c = key.channel() as SocketChannel
                while (!c.finishConnect()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                }
                println("连接服务器成功")
                c.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ)
            } else if (key.isReadable) {
                handleRead(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I create a SocketChannel,and regist it to a selector,and then attach an Object to the key.

when I receive the first OP_CONNECT event,I can get the attachment successfully.
but at the next OP_READ event, the attachment() returns null?

why?

Comment: You might want to include a tag indicating the language you're using.

Comment: I print the key, it shows that the key is the same one .

Comment: Which line seems to cause the problem?

Comment: [The doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SelectionKey.html#attachment--) says _"Returns: The object currently attached to this key, or null if there is no attachment"_ You never attach anything to `OP_READ`, only to `OP_CONNECT` (at least in this code).

Comment: @JornVernee yes, you are right. If i attach the object to the OP_READ event,it works.   but the key for OP_CONNECT and OP_READ is the same one. every channel use the same key for all it's  OP_EVENTS. but it sames like the attachment is independent for every event?

Comment: I did some testing, and you are right. Every key is the same, but I found out that only the last thing that is attached is saved, and the line `c.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ)` attaches `null`. I think you can achieve what you want by using `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`, which doesn't erase the attachment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

This creates a *new* registration, with a new `SelectionKey` and a new attachment: in this case `null`, as you didn't supply one. If you want to preserve the prior attachment, either just call `interestOps()` with new arguments, or else call `register(Selector, int, Object)` with the same attachment object as before.

BUT Your connect code is pointless. You put the channel into non-blocking mode, and then you execute essentially a blocking-mode connect the hard way, with sleeps. Just leave the channel in blocking mode, do the connect, *then* put it into non-blocking mode if you must and start the select loop. But the point of non-blocking, or even NIO for that matter, in a client, has always escaped me, unless you're planning to connect to lots of servers, or one server with lots of connections (like a spider).